# Reading excel cell data using Win32com throws exception in Robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, win32com

I'm trying to create and use an excel library (Password protected excel) for Robot framework by using Win32COM.

And through this library, trying to read the cell data, row count, column count etc.

Below are the functions created in the python library file:

```
def get_row_count(self, sheetname):
    self.ws = self.wb.Worksheets(sheetname)
    return self.ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

def read_cell_data_by_coordinates(self,sheetname, row_value, column_value):
    self.ws = self.wb.Worksheets(sheetname)
    return self.ws.Cells(row_value, column_value)
```

And both functions are returning the expected data's with below python code

```
if __name__=='__main__':
a = Excel3Library()
a.open_excel('C:\Users\/admin\Desktop\/Sample.xlsx')
print a.read_cell_data_by_coordinates('Sheet1',1,1)
print a.get_row_count('Sheet1')
a.save_excel()
```

Now the problem is, when I try to use the read & write functions via robot framework. It doesn't work and thrown below error whereas row & column count functions are working fine.

```
  com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: What happens if you call the exact same functions from a python script, without robot framework involved at all?

Comment: Not sure if the path in `('C:\Users\/admin\Desktop\/Sample.xlsx')` is correct. I'd probably write it like `('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Sample.xlsx')` or `('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Sample.xlsx')`

Comment: @BryanOakley - All the functions are working fine with Python and with robotframework get row count, column counts are working fine. Exception throws only while trying to read or write a cell via robotframework.

Comment: @A.Kootstra - With python, it works on both ('C:\Users\/admin\Desktop\/Sample.xlsx') and ('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Sample.xlsx'), whereas with robotframework, Only read & write methods are thrown exception.